# Given a function $f$ with $f(1\,940)=1\,000\,000$, and its derivative is equal to $kf(200-f)$ and $k$ is a constant. How can I get $f$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The problem is this:

Given a function $f$ with $f(1\,940)=1\,000\,000$, and its derivative is equal to $kf(200-f)$ and $k$ is a constant. How can I get $f$?

I've tried integrating $df/dx$ but I got $f(x) = -\frac{1}a(100f^2-\frac 13 f^3)$
but I don't know how to get this in terms of $x$.

Comment: Your constants are askew. The capacity of this logistic equation is $200$, it makes no physical sense to consider values this far away from it. You need to apply either separation with a partial fraction decomposition, or treat the equation as a Bernoulli DE. Your integration idea is just wrong, make the test and compute the derivative of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you had $dy/dx= y(5-y)$, you'd probably want to treat it as a separable equation:

$$\frac{dy}{y(5-y)} = dx.$$

Use partial fractions on the left and integrate to get something in terms of log's.  What you did was integrate with respect to $f$, not $x$, when the derivative was with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we have the DE:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)=\text{k}\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{n}-\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)\tag1$$

We can divide both sides by $\text{y}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{n}-\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)$, in order to write:

$$\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{n}-\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)}=\text{k}\tag2$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\int\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{n}-\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int\text{k}\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

And it is really not that hard to find:

$$\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{y}\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)-\text{n}}\right|=\text{k}x+\text{C}\tag4$$

---

Now, for your case we can solve for $\text{C}$ using the initial condition:

$$\frac{1}{200}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{10^6}{10^6-200}\right|=\text{k}\cdot1940+\text{C}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{C}=\frac{1}{200}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{5000}{4999}\right)-1940\text{k}\tag5$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{200}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{y}\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)-200}\right|=\text{k}\left(x-1940\right)+\frac{1}{200}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{5000}{4999}\right)\tag6$$